# Extrapolation and Splines

Tags: spline, extrapolation

If you have a smooth curve, and at a certain point in time you want to predict the next turning point, and you assume it is a non-periodic, stationary, smooth process, then what would be the best way to do so?

[image]

Say the current point in time is the red arrow and you want to predict where the green arrow will be..

Comment: I'm not sure this will work on the stock market. All jokes aside, could you elaborate on what process this is? It really does look like something like $sin(x) + ax+b$ would be a good fit. It's probably helpful to have a model of the process, preferably with the random (probabilistic) and non-random parts separate. Maybe this is better suited for [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: What makes you think this is related to financial markets? The process is a sine-weighted moving average. And no, this is not better suited for the stats guys. Sure is difficult to find the right expert for specific questions. Any pointers on that please? Thanks.

Comment: Don't you think that making predictions about the future is slightly related to the stock market? Of course you are the expert in your field, how dare I make such a silly joke about it. Is there any reason for the refusal to ask a stats guy about this? I merely proposed to ask at some other place where people are applying math to problems as yours on a daily basis. I think the amount of answers you received here suggests that it's reasonable to at least try it. Could you please elaborate further on how that sine weighted moving average comes to be? (or a model of the process)

Comment: Hi null. Thanks for getting back to me. I guess I am letting my frustration get the better of me. I am a stats guy (and an economist also; you got me). I have hired a small army of consultants and still it is not solved.. SWMA: the impulse response looks like the first half of a sinusoid. Your best friend google knows better. So imagine there was something you needed in a field you knew nothing about. Like.. Nouvelle cuisine or whatever. What are the indicators of future success? Of getting the problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd try:

As this does in fact involve some sine wave, a Fourier analysis comes to mind. The problem with that is that the "randomness" does not have a high frequency.

The apparent sinusoid shape of the curve just goes "further up" or "down" by $F-A$. The noise is very subtle and doesn't distort the wave entirely.

Of course, over a longer period, that might indeed be some other function. Say for example the given data represents page visits of a website. The obvious sine wave comes from the day/night cycle, the difference between two days ($A$ vs $F$), might be because $F$ is a weekend day. The difference between days would then have some periodicity of a week, which is hard to see if you only look at two days.

For a Fourier analysis to work you want to have a few periods of the entire curve. If you have a lot of data, you could try to find those low frequency components.

---

some speculation:

Within the given data, the term added to the wave looks like something simple like $ax+b$. If that's actually part of some lower frequency component may or may not be true.

Let's pretend that within the window that your image shows, the curve is indeed of the shape $sin(x)+ax+b$. Given a window of appropriate size (that is, a little bigger than the period of the obvious sine component), you could fit the data points within that window to the assume formula via regression and get some values for $a$ and $b$.

Place the window at the origin. Move the window to the right and find the values for $a$ and $b$ for each window position, $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ so to speak. This should provide some idea about how these two unknown terms behave. Can you identify a pattern in it? Is it something that can easily be extrapolated? If you try some different window sizes and different "error" terms, you should be able to receive something you can extrapolate into the unknown regions of $x$.